# c#でseleniumを利用すると利用メモリがどんどん増えていく

Tags: c#, selenium, chromedriver

c#でseleniumを利用しているのですが、下記コードの`var html = driver.PageSource;`を実行するたびに使用メモリが増えていき、すぐにメモリがいっぱいになってしまいます。
1時間もすると、利用メモリが4GBに到達し、OutOfMemoryExceptionを発生してしまいます。
`driver.Quit();`の前に`driver.Close()`を入れてみたり、下記コードはあるクラス内に書いているのですが、そのクラスにnullを入れたあと`GC.Collect()`などを実行したりしてみてるのですが、メモリが全く解放されません。

追記：Selenium.Webdriverのバージョンは3.141.0
Selenium.WebDriver.Chromedriverのバージョンは84.04147.3001を利用しています。

対象アプリケーションを無理やり再起動させて、などの処理も考えているのですがseleniumで利用したメモリを解放する手段をご存知の方がいれば、教えていただけるとありがたいです。。

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, options, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(this.Url);

ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(@"//a[@href!='' and normalize-space(.) != '']"));
var html = driver.PageSource;

elements = null;
driver.Quit();

// chromedriverのプロセスを破棄する
KillProcessAndChildren("chromedriver.exe");
driver = null;

return html;
```

Comment: var html = driver.PageSource; で、変数 html に開いているページのソースが入ります。
その大きさは、開いているページに依存します。
とりあえず、var html = driver.PageSource; の次の行に print(html); という行を追加して、どのようなデータを取得しているのかを確認してみてください。

変数htmlをnullにすると、ガベージコレクションされませんか？

Comment: htmlにはstringで対象ページのタグを含んだソースが入るようになっています。ご指摘していただいたようにnull（空白？）を入れてみます

Comment: 今までは変数htmlをreturnしたあと、それらをDBに保存してから変数htmlに空白を代入していたんですが、それをnullを設定するようにしたことで、少しメモリの上昇は抑えられたかもしれないです。
ただ1時間動かさないうちにメモリ使用量が2GBを超えているので、改善はしていないようです。。

Comment: ReadOnlyCollectionを使っていますが、何故でしょうか？
　ReadOnlyにしている(Writeできないので、クリアすることも出来ない）ために、ガベージコレクションの対象にならなくて、メモリを占有し続けているという可能性はありませんか？
　ReadOnlyCollectionを、Collectionに変更した場合の動作を確認してみてください。

Comment: なるほど、Readonlyについてはそこまで考えて及んでいませんでした。
サイトにあったものを流用したのですが今回のプログラムには不要みたいです

この処理自体をコメントアウトしたのですが、メモリが蓄積されていくのは変わらずでした。。

Answer (score 0):

質問するときは環境に関する情報を詳しく記述しましょう。
OSやIDE、ランタイムや仮想マシンのバージョンの些細な違いが重要であったりするケースもあります。

- [技術系メーリングリストで質問するときのパターン・ランゲージ](https://www.hyuki.com/writing/techask.html)

`KillProcessAndChildren()`の中では具体的に何をやっているのでしょうか？
`"chromedriver.exe"`を指定しているということは、おそらくWindows環境なのだと思われますが、そもそもSeleniumはクロスプラットフォームな自動化ソリューションなので、Windows環境前提のコードを無条件で記述している時点で何かがおかしいと考えたほうがよいと思います。もしプロセスを勝手に強制終了しているのだとすれば、そのせいで状態がおかしくなっている可能性があります。

`ChromeDriver`クラスは`ChromiumDriver`派生、`ChromiumDriver`クラスは`RemoteWebDriver`派生、また`RemoteWebDriver`クラスは`IWebDriver`インターフェイスを実装していますが、`IWebDriver.Quit()`ではドライバーの終了とすべての関連ウィンドウのクローズを実行する仕様らしいので、おそらく本来は`Quit()`メソッドを呼び出すだけでよいはずです。
また、途中で例外が発生しても`Quit()`メソッドが必ず呼ばれるように、`try-finally`文を利用するべきです。現状、`RemoteWebDriver.Quit()`の内部では単純に`IDisposable.Dispose()`メソッドを呼び出しているだけなので、`using`文を使うという手もありますが、今後も`using`文だけでよいかどうかは`RemoteWebDriver`の実装に依存します。

- [IWebDriver Interface](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_IWebDriver.htm)
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chrome/ChromeDriver.cs
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver/Chromium/ChromiumDriver.cs
- https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs
- [using ステートメント - C# リファレンス | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement)

`PageSource`のHTML文字列をDBに保存している、というのも気になります。そのDBがエントリをメモリにマッピングしたままの状態（いわゆる非意図的オブジェクト保持）になっていればメモリリークします。本当にメモリ使用量の問題がSeleniumに起因するものなのかどうかを見極めるため、対照実験の観点から、DB保存をしなかった場合にどうなるか、ということも試したほうがよいと思います。